# LaTeX editor with embedded video player

Tags: editors

I'm looking for a latex edito with an embedded video player because i'm transcribing a video lecture. Do you know any solution? It would be very comfortable because in this way i can stop and restart the video by using the space bar for example.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In what way what you propose would be different from having another software, say VLC, running the video alongside your LaTeX editor? Since the space bar is used to typeset your document, you would have to change the focus from the embedded video player to the editing area when pausing the video.

Comment: Hello @KersouMan i'm using VLC, but i ve to switch from one software to another with the mouse, instead if the video player were embedded, it would be easier to play/stop the video.

Comment: If you're on Windows, dragging a window to the middle-right or middle-left of the screen automatically resizes it to take up half the screen and lets you select a window to take up the other half. Put your video on the right, your editor on the left, and then Alt + Tab to switch window focus followed by Space to pause/unpause would still be pretty comfortable.

Comment: Hello @dbmag9 i prefer to use an editor with a video player to avoid to switch between windows with alt+tab or with the mouse.

Comment: You don't need a LaTeX editor to write LaTeX code, so any transcribing software which lets you save the result as a text file would do.

Comment: @Gennaro Arguzzi I don't know of any text editor able to play a video, it would be a weird feature. In any way, just assign a [global hotkey](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Global_hotkeys/) to the play/pause button of VLC and you're good to go, no need to change focus. However, it has to be a weird shortcut to avoid doing nasty things with any program that would be running.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I appreciate that, but I think you're very unlikely to find one, and I was hoping to be helpful given that you will (probably) have to compromise.

Comment: It also occurs to me that any text editor where the space bar was used to do something other than type a space would be very uncomfortable to use! (But I know that was just an example.)

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the suggestions, i'm going to use one of the solutions which you have indicated to me.